# Change Antlr Token based on other tokens

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

Is it possible to make the token type a type based on if the token exists on on the string?

For example:

```
Hello 100
and:
100 Hello
```

`WORD` would be Hello

`AMOUNT` would be 100

But for this:

```
100 3543
and:
3543 100
```

`WORD` would be 100

`AMOUNT` would be 3543

Basically, there will **only** be one `WORD`. The problem is defining which number is the `WORD`.

Or is this simply not possible with `Antlr`?

Comment: And how do you determine which number is `WORD` in your second example?

Comment: Good point. Lets say, take the first number as `WORD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is 'no' ('no' because it is a bad idea and 'no' because it can be done, but only by using a horrible kludge).

Recognition of the relative syntactic/structural positioning of well-defined token types is properly a parser issue. If the token types are not well-defined, then the syntax is ambiguous -- proper interpretation relies on semantics. In this case whether a token has been previously used semantically as a `WORD`.

Semantic issues are best handled in a tree-walker given the full parse-tree is present for analysis.

Consider:

```
phrase : a=ID b=ID ;

ID : WORD | NUMB ;
WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;

fragment WORD : .... ;
fragment NUMB : .... ;
```

Now, in walking the parse-tree, each `PhraseContext` node can be examined. The labeling of the `ID`s make it simple to determine relative ordering: each `PhraseContext` node will have variables

```
TerminalNode a; // the first ID in the node
TerminalNode b; // the second
```

Record the order of the `ID`s on first encounter in a scratchpad. On subsequent encounters, the scratchpad can be used to consistently define which `ID` should be considered a `WORD` or `NUMB`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, if you keep the order of WORD and NUMBER always the same. For instance:

```
phase: id NUMBER;

id: WORD | NUMBER;
WORD: ...;
NUMBER ...;
```

That should return `id` for the first token, regardless whether it is a number or a word and always returns a number for the second token.

It's not possible to allow ordering the two arbitrarily, with the parser alone. If arbitrary order is a must you could only parse both as ID, as suggested by @GRosenberg and do a semantic check afterwards, which of them is the more plausible WORD and which the NUMBER.

**Update**
Changed the `id` rule to a parser rule, to avoid trouble as mentioned by Jiri.

Comment: Yes, doing a semantic check afterwards and keeping everything as ID is the solution we are going to do! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since what you call `WORD` can be numeric as well as `NUMBER`, this is a parser decision, not lexer decision:

```
line: id NUMBER | NUMBER WORD;
id: WORD | NUMBER;
WORD: [a-zA-Z];
NUMBER: [0-9];
```